# Access shortcode parameters from template code

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, so I am stuck with this issue. I am using a shortcode to display posts based on Tags. The shortcode looks like this (I am not quoting the real shortcode, as most of it is irrelevant here):

`[theshortcode posts_per_page="5" taxonomy="post_tag" tax_term="265"]`

I have written a template that loops through the posts and displays them on a page. At the bottom of the template I want to display a message like the following, so that the viewer can click and open the page where all the posts that have the tag with ID 265 are listed:

`See all posts`

I am using this line of code at the bottom of the template:

`<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($atts['tax_term']); ?>">See all posts</a>`

but the template doesn't display anything. If I hardcode the term ID (265) the code works, but obviously the template would only be useful for a single tag. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, francom!  What happens if you just `echo $atts['tax_term'];`?  Is there anything there?

Comment: Thank you @ASGM!

`echo $atts['tax_term']` doesn't display anything...

Comment: How is `$atts` defined?  Seems like things are going wrong there.

Comment: I'm a little confused, though - it looks like you're already hardcoding the `tax_term` when you call the `[theshortcode ... ]`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `$atts` is an array that stores the shortcode parameters. It's defined in the function that loads the template.

Comment: The shortcode comes from a plug in. I put the shortcode in a standard WordPress page, and the template path is one of the shortcode parameters (sorry for omitting that). So, the shortcode actually looks like this:

`[theshortcode template="templates/custom-template.php" posts_per_page="5" taxonomy="post_tag" tax_term="265"]`

The template with the code that loops through the posts is loaded by a function from the plug in code. That's where $atts is defined. Apologies if this is confusing... I am figuring out stuff as I go along...

Answer (score 0):

Your template should have a variable that holds the term ID value and that can be used both in the short code and the footer link.

Example code:

```
<?php
$termId = <set the term id for this specific page>;
do_shortcode('[theshortcode posts_per_page="5" taxonomy="post_tag" tax_term="' . $termId . '"]");
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($termId); ?>">See all posts</a>
```

Comment: I think I omitted a piece of important information: this is a shortcode provided by a plug in. It displays a section in a standard WP page where there are other sections, widgets, etc. The template just loops through the results of the query and outputs the markup to display the posts' thumbnails. The path to the template is one of the shortcode's parameters (I apologize for having omitted that. So I should change the example to:

`[theshortcode template="templates/custom-template.php" posts_per_page="5" taxonomy="post_tag" ttax_term="265"]`

Answer (score 0):

For the record: I have found a solution by traversing the $wp_query object and identifying how to reference the right members. Here is how I did it. 
Thank you guys for putting me on the right track.

Shortcode:
`[theshortcode template="templates/custom-template.php" posts_per_page="5" taxonomy="post_tag" tax_term="265"]`

Template:

```
    $tax_term = $wp_query->posts->query_vars['tax_query'][0]['terms'][0]; 
    $tax = $wp_query->posts->query_vars['tax_query'][0]['taxonomy'];
    $the_term = get_term_by('id', (int)$tax_term, $tax);
    ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link((int)$tax_term); ?>">See all posts in <? echo $the_term->name; ?></a>
```